# Cant start activity in appCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-intent

i cant startactivity when i change activity to appCompatActivity;

```
public class NavigActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navig);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    final NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    //********   Introduction Button    **********
    ImageView introBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.introduc_image);
    introBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(NavigActivity.this, IntroductionActivity.class);
            startActivities(intent);
            Snackbar.make(view, "معرفی روستا", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
```

and in manifest file added:

```
        <activity
        android:name=".NavigActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".IntroductionActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_introduction"
        android:parentActivityName=".NavigActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="android.arisa.kalahroodfinal.NavigActivity" />
    </activity>
```

and error is :

> Error:(50, 17) error: no suitable method found for startActivities(Intent)
>   method Activity.startActivities(Intent[],Bundle) is not applicable
>   (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>   method Activity.startActivities(Intent[]) is not applicable
>   (actual argument Intent cannot be converted to Intent[] by method invocation conversion)
>   method ContextWrapper.startActivities(Intent[],Bundle) is not applicable
>   (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>   method ContextWrapper.startActivities(Intent[]) is not applicable
>   (actual argument Intent cannot be converted to Intent[] by method invocation conversion)
>   method Context.startActivities(Intent[],Bundle) is not applicable
>   (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>   method Context.startActivities(Intent[]) is not applicable
>   (actual argument Intent cannot be converted to Intent[] by method invocation conversion)

i changed intent argument `NavigActivity.this` to `view.getContext` or `getbasecontext()` but i still have error.

Comment: Use `startActivity` instead of `startActivities`

Answer (score 3):

its too late to answer but i just figure it out how to resolve. 
problem is about theme

i accept your appcompat theme is like that in values/styles.xml;

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
</style>
```

in AndroidManifest.xml;

activity that extends Activity

```
    <activity
        android:name="package.name.WelcomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

activity that extends AppCompat

```
<activity
        android:name="package.name.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
```

hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

It's `startActivity(intent);` not `startActivities(intent);`

Add also `finish();` to stop current activity